# Delete call on nested resource does not work for integration test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have been beating my brain against the wall on this problem I am having with Rails 3.2. I have a simple integration test that does this.

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserFlowsTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  fixtures :posts, :comments

  test "should delete comment" do
    post = posts(:one)
    comment = comments(:one)
    delete post_comment_path, :post_id => post.id, :id => comment.id
    assert_response :redirect
    assert_assign (:post)
  end
end
```

You may recognize the models from the Rails guide. Anyway, when I call `rake:integration` I end up with this.

```
test_should_delete_comment(UserFlowsTest):
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"comments"}
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:533:in `raise_routing_error'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:529:in `rescue in generate'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:521:in `generate'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:562:in `generate'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:587:in `url_for'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:148:in `url_for'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:213:in `post_comment_path'
    C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/testing/integration.rb:382:in `method_missing'
    C:/dev/blog/test/integration/user_flows_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UserFlowsTest>'
```

My routes are defined as such.

```
             root        /                                           home#index
     posts_search GET    /posts/search(.:format)                     posts#search
       home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)                       home#index
    post_comments GET    /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#index
                  POST   /posts/:post_id/comments(.:format)          comments#create
 new_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/new(.:format)      comments#new
edit_post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id/edit(.:format) comments#edit
     post_comment GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#show
                  PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#update
                  DELETE /posts/:post_id/comments/:id(.:format)      comments#destroy
            posts GET    /posts(.:format)                            posts#index
                  POST   /posts(.:format)                            posts#create
         new_post GET    /posts/new(.:format)                        posts#new
        edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                   posts#edit
             post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#show
                  PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#update
                  DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                        posts#destroy
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.create(params[:comment])
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end

  def destroy
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = @post.comments.find(params[:id])
    @comment.destroy
    redirect_to post_path(@post)
  end
end
```

Not sure what could be wrong here.

Comment: It looks like the problem is the redirect (or lack thereof?) in the comments_controller destroy action. Can you show us what that looks like?

Comment: Sorry, I did not get your response until much later. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used Test::Unit regularly in quite a while (using RSpec these days) but I don't recall having much need for integration testing. The bulk of the tests were unit and functional.

This particular test isn't really an integration test. It's not testing the flow of information across domains. It's simply ensuring that there is a redirect after destroying a nested resource. Here's what I'd try. Pardon any outdated syntax. Assuming a file `test/functional/comments_controller_test.rb`:

```
require 'test_helper'

class CommentsControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase
  fixtures :posts, :comments

  def test_destroy
    post = posts(:one)
    comment = comments(:one)
    delete :destroy, :id => comment.id, :post_id => post.id

    assert_redirected_to post_path(post)
    # and whatever else you want to test
  end
end
```

Comment: Sure, I was just surprised that the integration test on a nested delete failed. I can test create/read/update as part of a user story but not delete. Could this be a bug somewhere?